# Trying to Link to PhysX libraries in windows runtime application

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx, physx

I have a default, blank windows store application with the following code added:

```
#include<PxPhysicsAPI.h>

static physx::PxDefaultErrorCallback gDefaultErrorCallback;
```

I have the following in my Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies setting:

```
PhysX3CHECKED_arm.lib 
PhysX3CommonCHECKED_arm.lib
PhysX3ExtensionsCHECKED.lib
```

I have added the include directory: `MyPhysXPath\Include`

The libraries are in this directory: `MyPhysXPath\Lib\win8arm`

If I add that path to the "Library Directories" setting I get a LNK2019 error for PxDefaultErrorCallback.

If I add that path to the "Libraries WinRT Directories" setting I get a LNK1104 error for PhysX3CHECKED_arm.lib.

If I add that path to both settings I get the LNK2019 error.

It's easy to get the project to build by linking to the win32 libraries, but it won't run.

My questions are:

1. Am I right that I need to link to the winRT version of the PhysX SDK
   and not the x86 version for a windows 8 PC metro application?
2. Assuming that is correct, what is the proper way to link to the WinRT libraries?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia has a specific set of libraries to target WinRT on an x86 platform.

Answer (score 0):

if you are building for x86, you need to link to the x86 libs and if you are building for arm, you need to link to arm libs.  you need to add the libs path to the "Additional Library Directories".  make sure you do add all the libs required.  It seems you might be missing some lib.

Comment: I should have come back and updated this post. I contacted NVidia and they said they have a special version of the libraries for windows 8 modern, x86 apps. You have to make a special request to get the libraries and their licensing department is not responsive at all.